# How to convole 1d image array as getting same result with 2d filtering

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

I try to convert 2d image to 1d and the filter as well than I want to filter that image with the 1d filter and getting the same corresponding pixel responses as in the 2d convolving.

I have done

```
I1 = I(:)
filter1 = filter(:);
response = imfilter(I1,filter1,'conv')
response2d = imfilter(I,filter,'conv');
```

but `response` and `response2d` are not same with the matching entries.

How could solve that problem? Any suggestion?

Comment: Why would you even think that this is likely to work ?

Comment: I don't think they should be the same. If I1 is a 2D image then it makes sense to use a 2D filter. You are just stacking the columns on top of each other and then doing the same for the filter thus applying a nonsensical filter to a nonsensical image. Stick with 2D

Comment: Edited and clarified the questions. It is important, please upvote.

Comment: I agree that the OP did not word the question clearly, and that he is clearly a beginner, but his meaning was plain enough from the code. The initial responses clearly betrayed ignorance of the important subject of separable filters (along with a rather cavalier lack of empathy for the OP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convolving a 2D signal is mathematically not equal with convolving a 1D signal. So it can not produce the same result.

In the case for example that you have a mean filter, let's say:

```
A = [1/9 1/9 1/9;
    1/9 1/9 1/9;
    1/9 1/9 1/9]
```

Then for a pixel `P(i,j)` the result intensity will be affected by the value:

```
R(i,j) = 
1/9 * 
( P(i-1,j-1) + P(i-1,j) + P(i-1,j+1) +
P(i,j-1) + P(i,j) + P(i,j+1) +
P(i+1,j-1) + P(i+1,j) + P(i,j+1) 
)
```

If you spread the filter kernel and the signal in columns, then, if we say (for simplicity) that the pixel `P(i,j)` is somewhere in the middle of the row, and not close to the ends, the new value will be:

```
R(i,j) = 
1/9 * (
R(i-4,j) + R(i-3,j) + R(i-2,j) + R(i-1,j) +
R(i,j) +
R(i+1,j) + R(i+2,j) + R(i+3,j) + R(i+4,j)
)
```

of course in the new 1D signal the indexes will not be two dimensional but 
`R(i,j)` becomes `R( i + j*imageHeight )` because the signal is spread out.

It is obvious that the value for every pixel in the second case is calculating using **different neighbors** and therefore cannot be equal for any arbitrary image, maybe only for special occasions with specific periodic signals.

Comment: Small comment, but A is actually a mean filter not a median filter isn't it?

Comment: oh, yes, I meant mean. Language confusion, thanks.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the question, see my response above.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in general. **However**, for a very important class of filter kernels it is not only possible, but very efficient too. This is the class of the so-called *separable kernels*, which includes the mean (a.k.a. box-blur) filter, the gaussian blur, and every other kernel whose matrix *K* can be expressed as the *outer product* K = u * v of two vectors, i.e. the product of a column vector *u* with as many rows as K, and a row vector *v* with as many columns as *K*.

If this is the case, the 2D convolution of the image *I* with the kernel *K* is mathematically equal to the sequence of two 1D convolutions, namely the convolution of the columns of *I* with *u*, followed by the convolution with *v* of the result of the first convolution. See more info on separable filters [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/04/separable-convolution/).

If you are using a generic 2D kernel *K*, and don't know whether it is separable or not, the way to test it is to compute its singular value decomposition ([SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)) *K* = *U* * *S* * *V*, which you can do with any of a number of libraries. You then see if all the diagonal terms of the matrix *S* (the *singular values* of *K*) are very nearly zero except for the first one S(1,1). SVD libraries will normally produce the singular values in sorted order from largest to smallest, so you only need to verify that *S(1,1) > 0* and *S(2,2) / S(1,1) << 1*.
If this is the case, then it is *u == U(:,1)*, the first column of *U*, and *v == V(1,:)*, the first row of matrix *V*.

Comment: Yes you are right, the existence of separable filters didn't come to mind, maybe that's what the OP was looking for. I'm still not sure though, it's not very clear question.